# c# - SQL - speed up code to DB

Tags: c#, sql, performance

I have a page with 26 sections - one for each letter of the alphabet. I'm retrieving a list of manufacturers from the database, and for each one, creating a link - using a different field in the Database. So currently, I leave the connection open, then do a new SELECT by each letter, WHERE the Name LIKE that letter. It's very slow, though.

What's a better way to do this?

TIA

Comment: Can you post your current code / table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get one result set from one query and split that up.  There is quite a lot of overhead going out the the database 26 times to do basically the same work!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are going to fetch them all anyway, you might find it faster to fetch them in one go and split them into letter-groups in the code.

Looking at it from the other end, why do you need to fetch all the lists just to build a set of links? Shouldn't you fetch a single letter when its link is clicked?

Comment: @Marcelo: I assume OP is only creating links for manufacturers that exist, so there may be none starting with `X`, for example.

Comment: Splitting in the code makes sense in this case... Very easy to do once the database has them sorted by alphabet.

Comment: @OrbMan, that still doesn't warrant fetching everything. Your index page could use `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)`, which is _much_ faster than fetching everything.

Comment: Yes, I proposed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are doing up to 26 queries, which will never be fast. Often a single db query can take at least 40 ms, due to network latency, establishing connection, etc. So, doing this 26 times means that it will take around 40 x 26 ms, or more than one second. Of course, it can take much longer depending on your schema, data set, hardware, etc., but this is a rule of thumb that gives you a rough idea of the impact of queries on overall page render time.

One way I deal with this kind of situation is to use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx). Fetch all the records into the [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), and then you can iterate through the alphabet, and use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method to filter.

```
DataTable myData = GetMyData();
foreach(string letter in lettersOfTheAlphabet)
{
    myData.Filter(String.Format("Name like '{0}%'", letter));
    //create your link here
}
```

Depending on your model layer you may wish to filter in a different way, but this is the basic idea that should improve the performance a lot.

Assuming you are querying to determine which letters are used, so that you know which links to render, you could actually just query for the letters themselves, like this:

```
select distinct substring(ManufacturerName, 1, 1) as FirstCharacter
from MyTable
order by 1
```

Comment: Tempted to downvote anything that has the word `DataTable` in it. I'll try to resist :)

Comment: @Thorarin: I hear you - not trying to promote that method of querying data (esp. with MVC with strongly typed views), just needed a lowest common denominator to demonstrate the concept in the absence of knowing the OP's model layer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it smarter with a [**stored procedure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). Let the SP return *all* the information you need in *one* call, and suddenly you only have *one* database interaction instead of 26...

Comment: Why does this warrant a sproc?

Comment: @Marcelo: Stored procedures, the cause of, and solution to, all of life's problems. Oh wait, that's alcohol!

Comment: If your stored procedure ends up doing 26 separate queries, it's still going to be a lot less efficient as doing one big query...

Comment: @Marcelo, @Thorarin: My interpretation of the OP's intention is to perform 26 *slightly different* `SELECT` statements, which is why he didn't already do everything in one statement and split it in code. One query is definitely more efficient, but if the problem is to execute 26 statements as fast as possible, I'd rather do it with an sproc than with 26 calls from code.

Answer (score 0):

Bring back all the items in one set (dataset, etc..), either through stored procedure or query, including the field left(col1,1), and sorting by that field..

select left(col1,1) as LetterGroup, col1, url_column from table1 order by left(col1,1)

Then look through the whole resultset, changing sections when the letter changes.

Answer (score 0):

- First letter in the alphabet sucks (sorry) as discriminator. You do not neet to split them actually (you could just ask for "where name like 'a%'), but whatever you run for that gives you on average a 1/26 or so split of the names. Not extremely efficient.
- What do you mean with "creating a link - using a different field in the Database" - this sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: Why would that be bad design? Building a hyperlink based on the ID of the manufacturer, or an URL field for example, seems perfectly valid to me :P

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple ways u can do this.  1) create a view in your db that has all the manufactures and their website link and then continue to hit the view for each letter. 2) select all the manufactures once and store it in a .net dataset and then use that dataset to populate your links.

Answer (score 0):

This seems dirty to me, but you could create a first letter CHAR column and trigger to populate it.  Have the first letter from the manufacturer name stored in that column and index it.  Then select * from table where FirstLetter = 'A'.

Or create a lookup table with rows A - Z and set up foreign key in the manufacturer table.  Again you would probably need a trigger to update this information.  Then you could inner join the lookup table to the manufacturer table.

Then instead of putting 26 datasets in the page, have a list of links (A-Z) which select and show each dataset one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you right, you're making a query for **every manufacturer** to get the "different field" you need to construct the link. If so, *that's* your problem, not the 26 alphabetic queries (though that's no help).

In a case like that, the faster way is this one query:

```
SELECT manufacturer_name, manufacturer_id, different_field 
FROM manufacturers m
INNER JOIN different_field_table d
ON m.manufacturer_id = d.manufacturer_id
ORDER BY manufacturer_name
```

In your server code, loop through the records as usual. If you want, emit a heading when the first letter of the `manufacturer_name` changes.

For additional speed:

- Put that in a stored procedure.
- Index `different_field_table` on `manufacturer_id`.

Comment: Stored procedure is doubtful to matter for speed... Clustered index on `manufacturer_name` could be helpful though. Depends on how it's being used in other scenarios.

Comment: @Throarin - If he calls this a lot, and his actual query is more complex (which is likely), putting the code in a stored proc may help, and can't hurt.